# Symfony 2 data not rendering in RSS.XML file, but the data is there in the markup code

Tags: xml, rss, symfony

I am creating an RSS feed for my project, and currently the file that holds the RSS data (the XML file) is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
    <title>RSS Example</title>
    <description>This is an example of an RSS feed</description>
    <link>http://www.domain.com/link.htm</link>
    <lastBuildDate>Mon, 28 Aug 2006 11:12:55 -0400 </lastBuildDate>
    <pubDate>Tue, 29 Aug 2006 09:00:00 -0400</pubDate>
    {% for latestnews in news %}
    <item> 
        <title>{{ latestnews.title }}</title>  
        <description>{{ latestnews.content | truncate(500) | raw }}</description>  
        <link>../app_dev.php{{latestnews.url }}</link>  
        <guid isPermaLink="false">{{latestnews.url }}</guid>
        <pubDate>{{ latestnews.lastedit | date('jS F Y') }}</pubDate>  
        <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="{{ latestnews.mainImage }}"/> 
    </item>  
    {% endfor %}
 </channel> 
</rss>
```

However, when the page is viewed in the browser, everything except for the data and tags contained within the `{% for latestnews in news %}` and `{% endfor %}` displays. The actual latest news articles don't display. When I check the mark up code however, the latest news articles are displayed.

I've looked at other RSS feeds (such as the BBC News one) and I can't see any difference in what I've done to what they've done. Do I have to add something, a specific Symfony code, that makes it render items when it's inside a loop?

Cheers

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced I'm with you. What browser are you using? Are you saying that no `<item>`s appear? And how exactly are you checking, in each case, when you make a distinction between "when the page is viewed in the browser" and "When I check the mark up code"? Can you show us what you mean? If it's any help, the BBC News RSS feed uses an XSLT stylesheet for friendly in-browser rendering (see the line `<?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting" type="text/xsl" href="/shared/bsp/xsl/rss/nolsol.xsl"?>` in their feed.) That's the same approach taken by FeedBurner's "friendly" feeds.

Comment: Hi Matt, I was using Firefox, then used IE which pointed out that the <media:thumbnail> tag wasn't recognised. I've removed it and now the articles display. What I meant was that when the page is loaded on to the browser, the articles wouldn't render on the page. However, when I went to view the source of the page (right clicking on the browser and selecting view source) I could see the data in the markup.

Comment: Ah, okay. It's possible you might get the `thumbnail` element to work if you add the namespace for the RSS media module to your XML (e.g. use `<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">` instead of just `<rss version="2.0">`.) Without that namespace declaration, your XML isn't well-formed, as you're using the `media` prefix without declaring it. (The RSS media module is an optional RSS extension, described [here](http://video.search.yahoo.com/mrss), and isn't part of the basic RSS specification.)

Comment: I may try that. I didn't know that the RSS thing was that strict. I may include the thumbnail before launch. I'm just happy that I have something like this working!

Comment: It's mostly strict because of the way XML namespaces work. The word "media" in this case is just a user-defined shorthand that refers to the real namespace, and it could actually be any name you like. If you used the declaration `<rss version="2.0" xmlns:flibblepops="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">`, then it's perfectly valid to refer to your thumbnail element as `<flibblepops:thumbnail>` later, and it should work just as well as using "media" in RSS readers and browsers :) But for the XML to be valid, the prefix you use must already have been declared, to associate it with the real namespace.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for that. I will probably give it a try later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stemmed from using the `<media:thumbnail>` tag. Once this was removed all of the articles displayed properly. Bizarrely, it was Internet Explorer that helped me solve it!